# Using ProgressBar with Caliburn.micro

Tags: c#, wpf, progress-bar, caliburn.micro

In my WPF application I'm trying to bind the property 'Maximum' from the control 'ProgressBar' with a property from the ViewModel (with help of Caliburn.micro).

View (xaml):

```
<ProgressBar x:Name="CurrentProgress"/>
```

ViewModel:

```
private int currentProgress;
public int CurrentProgress
{
  get { return currentProgress; }
  set
  {
    if (currentProgress == value)
    {
      return;
    }

    currentProgress = value;
    NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => CurrentProgress);
  }
}
```

The question: Is there a way with Caliburn.micro to bind also the maximum value. I tried to create a property like:

```
private int maximumProgress;
public int MaximumProgress
{
  get { return maximumProgress; }
  set
  {
    if (maximumProgress == value)
    {
      return;
    }

    maximumProgress = value;
    NotifyOfPropertyChange(() => MaximumProgress);
  }
}
```

But this does not work. 
I was also searching in the Caliburn documentation, but wasn't able to find some help there.

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 6):

You can bind `ProgressBar.Maximum` like every other `DependencyProperty`. This should work:

```
<ProgressBar x:Name="CurrentProgress" Maximum="{Binding Path=MaximumProgress}"/>
```

Your `x:Name="CurrentProgress"` is converted into `Value="{Binding Path=CurrentProgress, Mode=TwoWay}"` so something like this should also work:

```
<ProgressBar Value="{Binding Path=CurrentProgress}" Maximum="{Binding Path=MaximumProgress}"/>
```

Comment: thanks for your answer. right, your answer works. but i thought "caliburn" allows it to bind this property over convention.

Comment: I don't think so. As far as I know Caliburn.Micro does not support more then one convention per `FrameworkElement`

Comment: There should be a way to set it up, ItemsControl binds both SelectedItem and ItemSource. I was hoping someone else had done the hard work but I guess I'll have to do it myself....